# What determines if your arrows break?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Being long range and silent the bow is one of the most useful stealth options in the game with the added benefit of sometimes getting your ammo back. My roommate claims that arrows will always break unless you get a head shot, in which case they will always be recoverable. In my experience however being able to recover your arrow seemed more or less random.

So the question: Is there something that determines whether an arrow breaks or not? or is it actually random?

Comment: Definitely not a headshot thing - I've recovered arrows from body shots a few times.

Answer (score 4):

Your roommate was misled; the arrows break at random. There are some people who have tried numerous tests to find the exact percentage. The results range from 80% retrieval to 20% retrieval. This, along with the difference between torso vs. head shot, makes the overall percentage random.

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting. However do you have a source or just in game experience?

Comment: You can actually look at the wiki. It'll give you more information. I believe the arrow has a 45% chance of breaking.

Comment: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/The-Last-of-Us-General/Arrow-Breaking-Mechanics/td-p/40708541 This has a few interesting theories that show it MIGHT not be random.

Comment: That thread reads like people making stuff up.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I was able to browse the wiki after I got off of work. It has no information on the chance to retrieve arrows. http://thelastofus.wikia.com/wiki/Bow